# rhel 7.2 getting Transaction check error: when installing ansible

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, ansible

we have rhel server version `7.2`

we intend to install the latest `ansible` version , with all others rpm's ( because rpm dependencies )

rpm - `ansible-2.9.7-1.el7ae.noarch.rpm`

[image]

```
yum localinstall -y *
```

in the end of installation yum returned with the following errors'

```
Transaction check error:
  file /etc/krb5.conf from install of krb5-libs-1.15.1-46.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package krb5-libs-1.13.2-10.el7.i686
  file /usr/share/man/man5/k5identity.5.gz from install of krb5-libs-1.15.1-46.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package krb5-libs-1.13.2-10.el7.i686
  file /usr/share/man/man5/k5login.5.gz from install of krb5-libs-1.15.1-46.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package krb5-libs-1.13.2-10.el7.i686
  file /usr/share/man/man5/krb5.conf.5.gz from install of krb5-libs-1.15.1-46.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package krb5-libs-1.13.2-10.el7.i686
  file /usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/ecpglib6-9.2.mo from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-2.el7_7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.i686
  file /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/ecpglib6-9.2.mo from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-2.el7_7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.i686
  file /usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/ecpglib6-9.2.mo from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-2.el7_7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.i686
  file /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.2.mo from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-2.el7_7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.i686
  file /usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.2.mo from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-2.el7_7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.i686
  file /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.2.mo from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-2.el7_7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.i686
  file /usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.2.mo from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-2.el7_7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.i686
  file /usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.2.mo from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-2.el7_7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.i686
  file /usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.2.mo from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-2.el7_7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.i686
  file /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.2.mo from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-2.el7_7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.i686
  file /usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.2.mo from install of postgresql-libs-9.2.24-2.el7_7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.i686
```

according to redhat ( https://access.redhat.com/solutions/158883 ) , we add the following lines in `yum.conf`

```
exclude=kernel*,*.i686
exactarchlist=*
```

so we do that ( according to redhat )

```
# package-cleanup --dupes
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id
# package-cleanup --cleandupes
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id
No duplicates to remove
# tail -2 /etc/yum.conf
exclude=kernel*,*.i686
exactarchlist=*
```

but still we get the same `Transaction check error:`

any idea how to resolve this situation?

***NOTE - ansible ( ansible-2.9.7-1.el7ae.noarch.rpm )  is installed successfully on rhel 7.6 ( but not on rhel 7.2 )***

Comment: It seems the base mistake was installing a 32-bit package in a 64-bit distro (postgresql-libs-9.2.13)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors such as

```
file /etc/krb5.conf from install of krb5-libs-1.15.1-46.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package krb5-libs-1.13.2-10.el7.i686
```

happen because packages of different architectures have to provide the same content for files they both provide, *i.e.* they have to be the same version.

Here you have a number of older versions of packages, as shipped in RHEL 7.2 initially, conflicting with the versions currently available. To install the updated packages for `x86_64`, you have to simultaneously install the updated equivalents for `i686`.

The simplest option is to keep your systems up-to-date, but I understand that’s not an option for you. You’ll have to download the `i686` packages from the same repository as your `x86_64` packages and install them at the same time. Make sure to only download packages which have conflicts; you only need to upgrade packages which are already installed, there’s no need to install the `i686` variants of all packages in your Ansible install set.

Comment: `postgres-libs` only contains the client libraries, there’s no certainty that the database server itself is 32-bit (or even on the same system).